# Postgres - SQL to match the first rownum

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following SQL to generate a row num for each record

```
MY_VIEW AS
    ( SELECT
            my_id, 
            (case when col1 = 'A' then
                        1
                  when col1 = 'C' then
                        2
                  else
                        3
                  end) as rownum
from table_1
```

So I have data look like this:

```
my_id        rownum
0001-A         1
0001-A         2
0001-B         2
```

Later, I want to use the smallest rownum for each unique "my_id" to do a inner join what another table_2. How should I proceed? This is what I have so far.

```
select * from table_2 
inner join tabl_1
     on table_2.my_id = table1.my_id
     and row_num = (...the smallest from M_VIVE...)
```

Comment: Do you just want to `use the smallest rownum for each unique "my_id" to do a inner join` (like you write) or actually only keep rows with the smallest `rownum` per `my_id` (and exclude others)? And can there be more than one row per `my_id` with the same smallest `rownum`? The exact table definition of `table_1` would help. Plus, *always* declare your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, I would recommend `distinct on`:

```
selecd distinct on (my_id) my_id
       (case when col1 = 'A' then 1
             when col1 = 'C' then 2
             else 3
        end) as rownum
from table_1
order by my_id, rownum;
```

However, you can just as easily do this using `group by`:

```
select my_id,
       min(case when col1 = 'A' then 1
                when col1 = 'C' then 2
                else 3
           end) as rownum
from table_1
group by my_id;
```

The `distinct on` approach allows you to include other columns.  It might be a bit faster.  On the downside, it is Postgres-specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MIN()` function for `rownum` against every `my_id` in `table_1` and use that in the join.

You would need to make sure `table_2` also has `my_id` field to make the join work.

```
select * 
from 
table_2 
inner join 
(select my_id, MIN(rownum) as minimum_rownum from tabl_1 group by my_id) t1
on table_2.my_id = t1.my_id;
```